# Side effects of removing Angular component wrapper tags from DOM

Tags: angular, dom

Lets say I have a component called `<hello-world>` that has the following HTML template:

```
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

By using this component and inspecting in DOM it renders like the following:

```
<hello-world>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</hello-world>
```

I don't want the wrapping elements of `<hello-world>` and `</hello-world>` so by writing few lines of Java Script code I remove them from DOM and everything still works fine.

I know this is not suggested by the Angular team, but just wondering if this will cause any side effects on how Angular operates?

For people who are interested to see the code on how to remove the wrappers. It is called from ngOnInit().

```
const self: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement
const parent: HTMLElement = self.parentElement

while (self.firstChild)
     parent.insertBefore(self.firstChild, self)

parent.removeChild(self)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: If you just want to render something without a wrapper, you can use <ng-container>

Comment: I think he wants to build components that can used in other components and when Angular adds it own component tags into the DOM, it makes the DOM invalid for certain CSS libraries like Bootstrap.
Imagine, if you want to build a component for input type="text" and use that input component in another component which makes a Boostrap Input-group.

Comment: As @sam360 mentioned, this is exactly one scenario that messes things up with having wrappers for components.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same selectors as a directive for components. I wouldn't recommend it, but it works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f86erf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here is a simple example of using the hello component inside a div

so essentially you want a selector with `[]` wrapped around it and it the contents of the component will be inserted into it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello,[hello]',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

and use

```
<div hello></div>
```

Personally only time i found a valid reason to do this was making svg components, that need specific tags. Other than that i would avoid doing this. Else if it just to do dom operations, then you should just use directives, they are meant for that.

Comment: I know about attribute selectors but that is not what I want and will not help to solve my problem. Our solution has specific guide lines and we need to use custom HTML elements (eg. <my-component></my-component> rather than <div my-component></div>. Second, even with having a div with directive will still add the <div> element to the DOM which will mess up things when we mix our components with third party libraries such as Bootstrap.